# Django DateTimeField is naive yet USE_TZ = True

Tags: python, django

I am having the following issue on my Debian server. NOTE: This issue does not happen on local Mac env, identical codebase.

```
if self.ends < timezone.now():Exception Type: TypeError at /dealvote/Exception Value: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware
```

I have done the following:

USE_TZ = True in settings.py
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' in settings.py
Installed pytz
Installed mysql timezone tables mysql_tzinfo_to_sql — (as suggested here)

Code:

```
ends = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

@property
def isEnded(self):
    if self.ends is not None:

        #Extra check to make sure self.ends is aware
        if timezone.is_naive(self.ends):
            self.ends.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

        #self.ends is not aware here. timezone.now() is aware as checked in django shell
        if self.ends < timezone.now():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

ends is set with the following:

```
def setEnd(self, mins, hrs, dys):
    self.ends = timezone.now()
    isFlashDeal = False

    try:
        minutes = int(mins)
        self.ends += timedelta(minutes=int(mins))
        isFlashDeal = True

    except Exception:
        pass

    try:
        self.ends += timedelta(hours=int(hrs))
        isFlashDeal = True
    except Exception:
        pass

    try:
        self.ends += timedelta(days=int(dys))
        isFlashDeal = True
    except Exception:
        pass

    if isFlashDeal == False:
        self.ends = None

    if timezone.is_naive(self.ends):
        self.ends.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Comment: You should put the solution as an answer on your own question (and keep your question as it originally was) to help people who encounter the same problem in the future.

Comment: Done now. It wouldn't let me at the time as I have too low rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing this line:

```
self.ends.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

to

```
timezone.make_aware(self.ends, timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

Solved the issue!